# How to execute list of Mono sequentialy

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a list of mono i would like to process but they have to be executed sequentialy and also should execute next one only after previous mono is complete.

```
private Mono<List<Result>> processGoals(List<> goals,Data data) {
    
    List<Mono<Result>> plans = goals
                              .stream()
                              .map(plan -> processGoal(plan, data))
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

I tried to use

```
return Flux.concat(plans).subscribeOn(Schedulers.single()).collectList();
```

But this executes the next mono before previous one is complete.

Answer (score 1):

```
.flatMapSequential(goal -> processGoal(goal, data), 1)
```

Last parameter concurrency 1 is very important. I have tried this before without concurrency parameter and that didnt work. Kudos to @Michael McFadyen

Comment: why not `concatMap`?

Comment: i believe concatMap could be another solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

[`Flux#concatMap`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#concatMap-java.util.function.Function-) is the best option for this case.

It will merge each mapped publisher sequentially and fire it one at a time without having to explicitly define `concurrency` parameter.

Here's a complete example:

```java
Flux.fromIterable(goals))
        .concatMap(goal -> processGoal(goal, data))
        .collectList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mixing two paradigms: Streams and Reactive Streams. You can try to go fully reactive.

Try following:

```java
Mono<List<Result>> res = Flux.just(goals.toArray(Goal[]::new))
                            .flatMapSequential(goal -> processGoal(goal, data))
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
                            .collectList();
```

Comment: you may want to use `flatMapSequential` to satisfy the "they have to be executed sequentially" requirement. You can also use the `concurrency` param to avoid having to switch `Schedulers` ie.
```.flatMapSequential(goal -> processGoal(goal, data), 1)```

Comment: You're right, I missed that.

Comment: I did try flatmapsequential but key here is the concurrency parameter which needs to be set as 1

Comment: I was trying to get the context right so that i can explain it is list of mono and that needs to be executed sequentially one at a time.

Comment: why not `concatMap`?