# Spring Webflux: Calling an endpoint inside flatmap not in parallel

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive

In the following code in Spring Webflux application, I am calling an endpoint "**myfunction**" which internally calls another endpoint. If the list contains 3 values, I will hit the "**cancel**" endpoint 3 times. Here is the question. I want to hit the endpoint one by one which means once I get response for 1st value in list then only I want to hit for second value and so on. I know it is reactive framework, still do we have any way to do without using delayElements.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("test")
@Slf4j
public class MyRestController {

  private final WebClient webClient;

  public MyRestController(WebClient webClient) {
    this.webClient = webClient.mutate().baseUrl("http://localhost:7076/test/").build();
  }

  @GetMapping("/myfunction")
  public void callTest() {
    Flux.fromIterable(List.of("e1", "e2", "e3"))
            //.delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
            .flatMap(event -> {
              log.info(event);
              return sendCancelRequest(event);
            }).subscribe(log::info);
  }

  public Mono<String> sendCancelRequest(String event) {
    return webClient.get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("cancel").queryParam("event", event).build())
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class);
  }

  @GetMapping("/cancel")
  public Mono<String> callMe(@RequestParam String event) {
    //try{Thread.sleep(5000);}catch (Exception e){}
    return Mono.just(event + " cancelled");
  }
}
```

For example:
Once I get response for "e1" then only I wanna to call "e2" as sequence and response matters for subsequent values in the list. Please assist here guys!

Comment: You can use `concatMap`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70178264/8909235

Comment: Great @lkatiforis, thanks mate! I am wondering how I missed concatMap.